# Is Redux + Effects a promising architecture for a complex Angular application?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx-effects

**For a scalable Angular application**, I am eager to use the redux pattern and use Effects, Actions and Entities. I think it makes the code more structured as you have to define Actions which will be used by an Effect to trigger side effects and a Store change. The data will be well structured and the code has to be located at a specific place, which doesn't give you much possibility to have a disorganised code.

Then, I am also wary of not choosing a solution that might end up being discontinued for whatever reason.

That is when I wonder if there is yet another better solution or at least a credible competitor. By 'better', I mean simpler (but not less scalable), and a solution that the community will build upon instead of opting for another route.

Is this architecture the state of the art in Angular?

Please, detail your answer and if necessary compare with Redux-Saga and Redux-Thunk or another solution.

Comment: I'm strongly against applying redux pattern to Angular applications. Use services as well as `@Input`, `@Output` to share data / states between components. [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction)

Comment: @Dino, This solution is good for a small app. In a big app with many developers, I expect to see a lot of exotic things and some spaghetti code.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you have a well planned architecture behind it, you shouldn't run in those problems. You might as well take a look at [micro frontend architecture](https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html) which can be a nice approach to your big app with many developers.

Comment: I see what you mean, but my experience showed me that a junior developer will say that and a medium-sized application becomes quickly unmaintainable. There is always a hack to fix a problem partly, but what about framing this with experience and finding the right mix (Redux, component interaction, Context, Web storage, Services)? It is not about always or never in this case, it is more about using technics wisely. A micro frontend architecture splits things too much for what I was meaning, so I think Redux is the right answer when you have a sizeable state to serve to different components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am strongly in favor of the redux pattern in Angular applications as it has the following **pros**:

- UI state is decoupled from the view
- Works extremely well with the container-presentation component architecture
- Well supported by the community
- the UI state becomes an additional debugging tool (dependant on your flavor of redux)

When used in tandem with the container-presentation component architecture, redux is an excellent choice for scalable applications.

But like any architecture, there are some **cons**:

- The redux pattern and the inherent benefit of decoupled UI state does not automatically equal organized code. It's just as easy for chaos to reign in your store models and in the communication between your store and components.
- You've no doubt heard it many times before: boilerplate code.
- There are a few flavors of redux for Angular with their own quirks and communities. If your flavor goes out of style, you're stuck with a rarely maintained library or a lot of work to switch it out.
- It will heavily influence the architecture of your app. It's therefore important that all (or at least the most opinionated) developers on the team are on board with it. Some people just don't like it. That's fine too, so long as they also provide an equivalent or better (and concrete) solution.

#### Decoupled UI State

Redux apps use a `store` to save all UI state which, dependant on your component architecture, can be accessed by specific or all components to update the view. This, of course, does not mean you can't have internal component UI state that disappears when the component is destroyed.

Having the (global) UI state decoupled in this way allows you to use it in different ways, which you most often will do through the use of so called selectors. It's analogous to a using a database to obtain all the data you need to fulfil a server request.

#### Container-Presenation Component Architecture

Although not part of the redux pattern, I would argue the redux pattern is only acceptable in Angular when used with the container-presentation pattern. You may have also seen it called the smart-dumb component pattern. It's basically MVC for Angular.

**Container Components:** You split your app into feature domains and/or screens, each of which gets a so-called "container component". Per feature, this is the only component (with some necessary exceptions) that is allowed to communicate with the UI state and other app-wide dependencies (e.g., Router, ActivatedRoute). The container acts as the controller for the leaf nodes (presentation components) it uses.

The container component contains all the business logic for your feature domain/screen and coordinates the communication between its separate presentation components and app-wide dependencies such as the store, router, and services. Note that I also include typical angular services like router and activated route - there is rarely a good reason for a purely presentational component to access the URL or query parameters. They should be getting this data via inputs (which has another bonus of being easier to unit test).

Unfortunately, sometimes it is just easier to have a container nested in a container. For example, in child routes, sending data through a router-outlet is usually not worth the effort. Also, passing on data through inputs for deeply nested components can become tedious.

**Presentation Components:** All other components are the presentation components (dumb components) which know nothing of the rest of your app. In order to set up their HTML template, they get the data through their @Inputs. They also should not (directly) cause any side effects outside of their HTML template. For example, to change UI state it doesn't send an action directly to the store, but instead informs the container through an @output that something happened, and the container decides whether an action should be sent.

Neither does the presentation component cause any other side effects. They always use @outputs to inform the container component, which decides what to do with the information. For example, your presentation displays a list of superheroes. When a user clicks a superhero for more info, your presentation doesn't open a new page (it knows nothing of pages). It instead sends an event through its @output with a superhero ID to the container. The container can then open a new page, or open a popup, or to update a sibling component, etc. In this way your presentation components become more reliable, easier to test and more reusable while your UI state changes and other side effects are confined to your container components.

The alternative - to allow every component to communicate with the store or cause other side effects - is an anti-pattern that will defeat a lot of the benefit of decoupling your UI state. It also means that you could potentially have actions flying from any point in your app.

#### Community / Angular Redux Flavors

There is a lot of interest for the redux pattern, not only in Angular and React but in native iOS and Android as well. There are several flavors of redux on Angular that seem to have enough traction to be around for a while, notably ngrx/store.

The redux concepts in Angular are slightly different than in React. For example, redux-thunk is a react library and angular doesn't have exactly the same thing (please note if that's incorrect). In ngrx/store, actions are handled within an effect and the use of observables, which can take some getting used to. Also, chaining multiple effects may be necessary to achieve the same result as a redux-thunk.

As far as redux flavors in angular, some of the most popular are:

- ngrx/store
- ngxs/store
- akita

Dead, or no longer well maintained:

- angular-redux (sadly)

#### UI state as debugging tool

ngrx/store (at least) offers the use of the Chrome Redux DevTools extension. This is an excellent tool to inspect your redux store and how it changed each time an action was dispatched.

#### Boilerplate

When using redux in its raw form, you're going to write a lot of boilerplate code. This can be reduced in a few ways:

- Write your own factories. For example, write an factory function for actions that returns an object with 4 actions: load, success, error, reset. Correspondingly create effect and reducer factories that all handle the redux pattern in defined ways.
- ngrx has it's own variant of redux entities that reduce boilerplate code in a similar manner to the "roll your own" approach above
- ngrx has recently incorpated the ngrx/data library which even further abstracts a few things in redux to virtually remove the need for boilerplate code

#### Organized Code

As mentioned above, your store can very quickly become disorganized as the app grows. Often we think of the store as a mirror of the view and define our store based on the first view that's built. We then end up with a lot of duplication in the store that needs to be refactored out.

By instead taking a step back from each specific view to take a look at the UI state required by multiple views and at least partially normalizing the store, you can lean on selectors to compose the UI state that the each view needs.

Unlike Redux in React, it's possible to have separate stores by splitting them up in feature modules. While this seems like a good idea at first, it often leads to trouble when you need to share state between modules, especially when you have lazy modules. In the end it's usually not worth the trouble, so I recommend starting with one store at the app module level until you absolutely find a need to split up the store.

Comment: Thank you! This question is often opinionated because we forget the context. A store, Effects or Entities have a cost, as well as learning. Using different technics wisely saves on complexity and spaghetti code. I saw too often how it gets quickly complicated to develop because the code is not organised. You lose performance, flexibility, maybe agility and what about the Ui or UX in the end? The boilerplate code is annoying and functional reactive programming is complex, but your application becoming a nightmare is worst. Redux reduces your freedom, but it also makes you more powerful.